# How to deploy C++ project with all dependencies?

Tags: c++, cmake, installation

I am working on a C++ project that requires third-party libraries (`boost`, `poco`, etc). I use `cmake/make` to install the package to an install location and deploy it to the production machine. However, when pushing the app to another machine, the shared libraries are not present on the target machine causing `ld` errors. Is there a standard way to detect dependencies (i.e. shared libs) and deploy them to the install location along the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Linux Deploy Qt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt).I use it for deploying my Qt application written in C++. Apart from Qt, it also puts other non-Qt dependencies(libraries) into a single directory. just run it with the executable as the argument.